# How can I apply multiple functions involving multiple columns of a pandas dataframe with grouby?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-apply

Considering the following datafrme:

|  | id | cat | date | max | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | s1 | A | 12/06 | 9 | 5.4 |
| 2 | s1 | B | 12/06 | 10 | 5.4 |
| 3 | s2 | C | 11/04 | 13 | 4.2 |
| 4 | s2 | D | 11/04 | 28 | 10 |
| 5 | s3 | E | 08/02 | 16 | 5.4 |
| 5 | s3 | F | 08/02 | 6 | 5.4 |

I want to group by "id" and get the first of the columns [cat, date] but at the same time I want to get the mean of the max - score columns.
I think it can be done with an aggregate:

but with aggregate I can't access all the columns of the dataframe.

| id | cat | date | mean(max-score) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| s1 | A | 12/06 | 4.1 |
| s2 | C | 11/04 | 13.4 |
| s3 | E | 08/02 | 5.6 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first need to assign `max-score` to `mean(max-score)`, then this is a simple `groupby`+`agg`:

```
(df.assign(**{'mean(max-score)': df['max']-df['score']})
   .groupby('id', as_index=False)
   .agg({'cat': 'first', 'date': 'first', 'mean(max-score)': 'mean'})
)
```

output:

```
   id cat   date  mean(max-score)
0  s1   A  12/06              4.1
1  s2   C  11/04             13.4
2  s3   E  08/02              5.6
```

Comment: The answer was very helpful, thank you very much, but I still have a question, what is the function of the “**” operator?

Comment: The `**` is to expand the dictionary into parameters of the `assign` method. `X(**{'A': 'B'})` is equivalent to `X(A='B')`, but also enables to use "A" names that are not valid python parameter names (such as `mean(max-score)` due to the parentheses and dash).

Answer (score 2):

From pandas 0.25 onwards, you can also use [pd.namedAgg](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html?highlight=filter), a very useful function:

```
df['diff'] = df['max'] - df['score']
df.groupby('id').agg(cat=pd.NamedAgg(columns='cat',aggfunc='first'),
                         date=pd.NamedAgg(columns='date',aggfunc='first'),
                         mean(max-score)=pd.NamedAgg(columns='diff',aggfunc='mean'))
```